# How to put multiple conditions (one or and two and) in np.where function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I have a numpy array of several rows and three columns. I want to do a `np.where` function to find two rows among all the existing rows. The first row I want is the row that has the least values of the second column and also its third column is the minimum one among others. The second row is among the rows that have the highest values in their second column. And my target has the least value of in its third column among these rows. It is my data set:

```
arr=np.array([[6. , 1. , 1.2],
              [5.5, 3. , 1.5],
              [5. , 1. , 2. ],
              [5. , 3. , 2. ],
              [5. , 6. , 2. ],
              [4. , 1. , 3. ],
              [4. , 3. , 3. ],
              [4. , 6. , 3. ],
              [3. , 1. , 4. ],
              [3. , 3. , 4. ],
              [3. , 6. , 4. ]])
```

Then I tried using two `&` and one `|`:

```
arr[np.where(((arr[:,1]==min(arr[:,1])) & (arr[:,-1]==min(arr[:,-1]))) |
             ((arr[:,1]==max(arr[:,1])) & (arr[:,-1]==min(arr[:,-1]))))]
```

To get the

```
np.array([[6. , 1. , 1.2], [5. , 6. , 2. ]]
```

But it is only giving me:

```
np.array([[6. , 1. , 1.2]]
```

I do appreciate any help to solve my problem.

Comment: What if the least values of the second and third columns are not in the same row? What are you going to extract then?

Comment: Dear @Virtuoz, Thanks for this comment. This is my bad. I meant among all the the rows that their second column is minimum, I want the row that its third column is also minimum. For the second row, among all the rown that their second column is minimum, I want the row that its third column is minimum,

Comment: The key to using `np.where` (Or in this case `np.nonzero`) is to get the condition array correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as you expected

```
arr1 = arr[arr[:,1]==min(arr[:,1])]
arr1 = arr1[(arr1[:,-1]==min(arr1[:,-1]))]

arr2 = arr[(arr[:,1]==max(arr[:,1]))]
arr2 = arr2[(arr2[:,-1]==min(arr2[:,-1]))]

np.concatenate([arr1, arr2])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a1 = arr[:, 1]
a2 = arr[:, 2]
a1mn = a1.min()
a1mx = a1.max()
ia1mn = (a1 == a1mn)
ia1mx = (a1 == a1mx)

out = arr[(ia1mn & (a2 == a2[ia1mn].min())) | (ia1mx & (a2 == a2[ia1mx].min()))]
```